# Charset Doctrine Issue

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I am beginner and currently working on a SYMFONY 4 project . I have a  migration problem with Doctrine. “php bin / console doctrine: migrations: migrate”  returns an error because the migration file is not encoded in the usual way: special characters are present in mysql queries. I use mysqlworkbench for my database.

src/Migrations/Version...:

```
public function up(Schema $schema) : void
{
    // this up() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
    $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() !== 'mysql', 'Migration can only be executed safely on \'mysql\'.');

    $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE test (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` ENGINE = InnoDB');
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE user CHANGE mentor mentor VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CHANGE referent referent VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL');
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE integration_step ADD font_awesome VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, ADD color VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL, ADD number INT NOT NULL, CHANGE na?me name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL');
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE checklist_item CHANGE na?me name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL');
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE role CHANGE na?me name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL');
}

public function down(Schema $schema) : void
{
    // this down() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
    $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() !== 'mysql', 'Migration can only be executed safely on \'mysql\'.');

    $this->addSql('DROP TABLE test');
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE checklist_item CHANGE name na?me VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`');
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE integration_step DROP font_awesome, DROP color, DROP number, CHANGE name na?me VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`');
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE role CHANGE name na?me VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`');
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE user CHANGE mentor mentor VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`, CHANGE referent referent VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`');
}
```

}

A message informs :

> "No data sources are configured to run this SQL and provide advanced code assistance"

Is anybody can help me ?
Thank’s

Comment: I would advise to *not* use non-ascii column names at all. please check your entities' properties and annotations. both the property names as well as the `name` attribute in their `@ORM\Column` annotation. My opinion on this is: when you use non-ascii column names you're on your own. (it's probably frowned upon by most developers)

Comment: okay, it seems like your database tables have already non-ascii chars in them. and the migration tries to ascii-fy them. (which is a good idea)

Comment: Yes i agree with you. Do you think it's could be a Doctrine issue ?

Comment: maybe. it's probably some encoding issue. I guess you should just manually edit the file such that `a?` is replaced by the proper accented character.

Comment: Good news !!! I fixed the issue by install Doctrine again and maker-bundle. Thank's for your advices. I executed `composer require symfony/orm-pack` and `composer require symfony/maker-bundle --dev`